# How to implement a variable operator in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, syntax, conditional-statements, comparison, operators

I am not sure if 'variable' is the correct word to use here but essentially, I would like to create a variable operator using JavaScript.

So far, the best thing I can think of is to create a switch statement but it seems very repetitive and tedious to do. Is there any way I can write one "If Statement" with a conditional operator?

What I have thought of:

```
variableOperator(x, y, operator) {
    switch(operator) {
        case '>=':
            if (x >= y) {
                // logic
            }
            break;
        case '<=':
            if (x <= y) {
                // logic
            }
            break;
        case '<':
            if (x < y) {
                // logic
            }
            break;
        case '<':
            if (x < y) {
                // logic
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

What I am wondering if is possible in pseudo-code (code below will obviously not work but in concept, this is what ideally I would like to use). No matter what the operator is (greater than, equals to, etc.) this if statement can take care of it:

```
variableOperator(x, y, operator) {
    if (x operator y) {
        // logic
    }
}
```

Edit: I should have clarified: x and y don't always have to be number types.

Mainly, I'm wondering about string (a-z,A-Z,0-9) comparison (== or !=) and number comparison (<, >, <=, >=). The project I'm working on does not need to worry about emoji's or other complex characters.

In essence, regardless of whether I'm comparing strings or numbers, I'm wondering if the operator itself can be a variable that can be easily manipulated/changed so that one would't have to write a separate bit of code for each case.

Comment: No, these are language level instruments we don't have the ability to manipulate in that way.

Comment: Are these the only operators you are concerned with? And will `a` and `b` only be Number types?

Comment: What do you expect `variableOperator("foo", "bar", "")` to produce?

Comment: @RandyCasburn/VLAZ - Good catch. I hope I clarified in my edit above in the post.

Comment: My original comment stands. The answer is no. But your premise is still flawed as far as I can tell. In your example you have 4 conditional statements in 4 cases with independent logic based upon the conditional - yet your ideal solution would have you pass an operator somehow and only use a single bit of logic? It seems logical that you would still need 4 independent bits of logic - where would those go?

Comment: You can use `eval` but it's usually it's the beginning of a bad approach, at least. What are you trying to do where you have operators passed in? If you know that you need to pass in `4`, `2`, and `>` you can probably also do `4 > 2`. If you don't know the operator upfront, you can just encode all operators you want supported in a lookup table. Should take about five minutes.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Ultimately, a user from the UI can send a value, let's say 1, and through other factors, I eventually have a dynamic comparison between 1 and x. I would like to see if that comparison is true or not. x is a call I make to the database and along with x, I get an operator back. So instead of making a call to the database, and then doing a switch statement, I'd like to simply say: Here's 1, lemme see what check we're doing. We're doing "Less than" "2". If we combine this in an If Statement, is the comparison true?

Comment: @RandyCasburn Essentially, if the comparison is true, that logic I would like to perform is always the same. For example, let's say I make a pop-up saying 'That statement is true'. So for me, I think it would be a bit redundant if I were to make a switch statement when the logic performed when the if statement is true, would be all the same

Comment: My brain is yelling "functional approach", "functional approach" - was thinking currying similar to this: http://plnkr.co/edit/Jqbu07cd9bFFTMtVrz5c - but then VLAZ came up with a brilliant solution. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Encode your operators in a lookup table and then you can use that in order to determine what to do. This reduces your code to just an `if` statement to check if the values pass the operator check. You can also include a fallback - if the operator is not found, just assume it fails.

```js
const operators = {
  ">" : (a, b) => a > b ,
  ">=": (a, b) => a >= b,
  "<" : (a, b) => a < b ,
  "<=": (a, b) => a <= b,
  "==": (a, b) => a == b,
}

function doStuff(x, y, op) {
  const check = operators[op] ?? (() => false);
  
  if (check(x, y)) {
    console.log("do something");
  } else {
    console.log("ignore");
  }
}

doStuff(4, 2, ">");
doStuff(2, 4, "<");
doStuff("apple", "banana", "<");
doStuff(4, 2, "==");
doStuff(4, 2, "");
```

Comment: Brilliant. I was going to recommend currying in a similar fashion, but this works.